# I have a question about Cloud Firestore V9 and using React Js. In one of my docs, there is a map. How do I access this map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image: firebase screenshot]

[image]

There's a function named getSomethingTEST that I'm using to get the data. Then I have a 'temporary' button onPress={getSomethingTest}, but probably its going to be a useEffect not a button. Later I was going to set my state var "dataFB" to the tempStore array.
But my issue is... I don't know how... So I tried to console.log my results of tempStore. And I got this.. [the results in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gi3YB.png) Which I believe is a nested object inside of an array. So I tried some basic things like tempStore[0].name but its of course undefined. Also I wasn't sure how to reference a key of an object that has a space in it. For this example it was "Asem Jawa".

```
    const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
    apiKey: "Hidden",
    authDomain: "Hidden",
    projectId: "Hidden",
  });

  const db = getFirestore();
  const col_p = collection(db, "WNA-Pasteur");
  const docRef = doc(db, "WNA-Pasteur", "branchData");


  const [dataFB, set_dataFB] = useState([]);

  async function getSomethingTEST() {
    const tempStore = [];
    const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
    tempStore.push(docSnap.data());
    console.log(tempStore);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fetching a single document and `docSnap.data()` is an object containing that document's data. You don't have to push it an array that way.

```
async function getSomethingTEST() {
  const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
  console.log(docSnap.data().name)  
}
```

This should log the name but in your case, you don't have a property `name` in your object so it'll be undefined.

> I wasn't sure how to reference a key of an object that has a space in it.

You can use [brackets notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation):

```
console.log(docSnap.data()["Asem Jawa"] || "Field missing")
```

Comment: Thank you this worked! But I have another question about using square brackets "[ ]" for the "Asem Jawa". Is this just normal JavaScript or is this a part of Cloud Firestore? And what does it mean specifically?

Comment: @user3662944 that's a Javascript thing. Read the link I've mentioned in my answer. Essentially `myObject["user"+2]` will calculate anything in the `[]` and access that property. In this case it'll be value of `myObject.user2`